# How to handle input of varying datatype during deserialization?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm trying to download json data where one of the attributes is `"easting"`. For the majority of the json dataset, `"easting"` is an integer, but there are a handful of cases in which `"easting"` is a list of integers as shown below:

```
"easting" : 357570 ,
...
"easting" : [ 434939, 434942 ] ,
```

My original code had anticipated `"easting"` to be an `int` when its class was declared as follows:

```
public class Item
{
    public int easting { get; set; }
}
```

However, I keep getting errors saying that I cannot convert a type `int` to a type `int []`. If I adjust the class definition to allow `easting` to be of type `int []`, I simply get the reverse error - I cannot convert a type `int []` to a type `int`.

How can I go about handling this? Is there any way to account for a varying input datatype during the deserialization process?

Comment: Can you use a dynamic? Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147272/serialize-a-json-property-that-is-sometimes-an-array

Comment: If you're using Json.net, then this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n)

Comment: @stuartd I'm currently using the `JavaScriptSerializer` from `System.Web.Script.Serialization` though I might try switching to Json.net as that example does seem straightforward. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I followed the suggestion from @stuartd and swtiched from `JavaScriptSerializer` to `Json.net` for the deserialization process, which allowed me to follow along with the [question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n) and resolve my issue.